# How to create temp tables on the fly on mysql and does it help performance?

Tags: mysql

I have a MS TSQL background and i was wondering how to do the ff. in mysql and does it have the performance benefits like in SQL SERVER when using the temp table as cache data?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #product_customer

SELECT p.*,c.FullName
INTO #product_customer
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN product_taken p
on p.customerid = c.customerid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE product_customer
SELECT p.*,c.FullName
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN product_taken p
on p.customerid = c.customerid
```

when the user session ends, temporary tables are dropped automatically. However you can always explicitly drop temoporary tables by issuing `drop temporary table ....` command.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE product_customer
```

*does it have the performance benefits like in SQL SERVER when using the temp table as cache data?*

this is very subjective question and it depends on your data and the use case. It is hard to say yes or no.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how do you know a temp table is a temp table?  mysql does not have a # sign?

Answer (score 2):

The temporary table can improve performance significantly if you need to refer to it in multiple queries. If you wrote it as a subquery in each of those queries, the engine would have to search for those rows each time.

You can also add indexes to the temporary table, which is not possible with subqueries.

However, there's one important limitation: you can only refer to a temporary table once in a query -- you can't self-join the table, for instance. If you need to do this, you'll have to duplicate the temporary table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE product_customer2
SELECT * FROM product_customer
```

Comment: "The temporary table can improve performance significantly if you need to refer to it in multiple queries" unless MySQL chooses to convert the RAM temporary table to disk based because off the low temporary table based server settings, then you will have to deal with random disk I/O and disk writes which is **slow** without a doubt.

Comment: It's still likely to be better than recomputing it multiple times, if the query is complex.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the input.  "only refer to a temporary table once in a query".  This is interesting.  We dont have this restriction in MSSQL.  I think this is by design and most likely to release resources ASAP.   But it's 2019 and i would think a simple syntax change like CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE product_customer PERSIST_ENTIRE_SESSION would be sufficient to notify the engine not to release the resources until exiting the routine.

Comment: "It's still likely to be better than recomputing it multiple times, if the query is complex." Well if you would add index(es) to the temporary table it might be.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I mentioned adding indexes in my answer.

Comment: If need to use twice in a query, create a second, identical, temp table:  `create temporary table temp2 select * from temp1;` Then use each table once in the query.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve That's what I said in the last line of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code snippet now; I missed that last line.